# How to update timezone of a running java webapp(without restarting) if timezone is updated in underlying OS?

Tags: java, web-applications

I am trying to update/access(updated) timezone in a running java webapp, when timezone of underlying OS which in my case is a linux distro, is updated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest you set the timezone correctly before you start your application. If this is not possible use a generic timezone like GMT and always set it explicitly in the application.  When you set the timezone and open any program, the timezone for that program doesn't change (this is not specific to Java)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you need the timezone, try to call from your webapp

```
TimeZone.getDefault();
```

docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29):